# Objective c - CCCryptorStatus without CCOptions

Tags: objective-c, encryption, commoncrypto

I would like to know, how can I define a CCCryptorStatus without using CCOptions. The documentation said, if I don't set the kCCOptionECBMode, the default is CBC mode, which is good for me. But I don't need for kCCOptionPKCS7Padding too, so how can I set this?

I try:

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(opMode,                   /* Defines the basic operation: kCCEncrypt or kCCDecrypt */
                                      kCCAlgorithmAES128,       /* Defines the encryption algorithm */
                                      0,...
```

but this is the correct way? Because if I want to use this method, I get an NSData object with full of 0, but with the correct size. So I don't think this value is good...
Thanks for any reply, madik

Comment: Was dealing with the same issue. Why you do not want to use kCCOptionPKCS7Padding?

Comment: My app communicates with a server, which is created in Java. The server don't use padding in some cases, that's why I don't have to use padding too in these cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I encountered this problem, I had to use kCCOptionPKCS7Padding. As far as I can see it's the only solution.

Please note, that using of the padding increases the security.

Comment: Meanwhile the question is solved, the problem was on server side. So it seems to fine to encrypt on a java server with AES/CBC/NoPadding Cipher, and you decrypt with 0x0000 CCOptions on an iPhone client side...But I accept your answer, because you're rigth anyway...